# Having problems whit a 8ball command on discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

If users say !8ball (question) it works fine, but if they only say !8ball without a question, it does not answer the message to ask a question "Escriba una pregunta."

```
  function doMagic8BallVoodoo() {
    var rand = ['Si?', 'No me digas :0', 'nose, espero haberte ayudado', 'No >:)', 'Si tu lo crees', '._.', 'Si!'];

    return rand[Math.floor(Math.random()*rand.length)];
}

// Later in the code:
if(command === "8ball")
 if (!args) return message.reply(`Escriba una pregunta.`);
{
    message.channel.send('**La respuesta a tu pregunta es** ' + doMagic8BallVoodoo());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if `args` is an empty array, your if statement will never return true. This is because `![]` does not equal `true`.

Instead, you should be checking if `args.length` or `args[0]` is falsy. If an array is empty, `args.length` will return 0, which is a falsy value (`!0` equals true), and `args[0]` will return `undefined`, which is also a falsy value (`!undefined` equals true).

Also, you placed your brackets *after* the `if` statement, which doesn't seem right.

```js
function doMagic8BallVoodoo() {
 var rand = [
  'Si?',
  'No me digas :0',
  'nose, espero haberte ayudado',
  'No >:)',
  'Si tu lo crees',
  '._.',
  'Si!',
 ];

 return rand[Math.floor(Math.random() * rand.length)];
}

// Later in the code:
if (command === '8ball') {
 if (!args.length) return message.reply(`Escriba una pregunta.`);
 message.channel.send(
  '**La respuesta a tu pregunta es** ' + doMagic8BallVoodoo()
 );
}
```

```js
console.log(![]); // false
console.log(!0); // true
console.log(!undefined); // true
```